# indexOf() Strange Java.util.List behaviour with duplicate Strings

Tags: java, list

I've just come across some odd behaviour I wouldn't expect from an `ArrayList<String>` in Java. This is coming, for sure, from my poor understanding of references in Java.

Let me show you this piece of code:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();

myList.add("One");
myList.add("Two");
myList.add("Two");
myList.add("Three");

for (String s : myList){
  System.out.println(myList.indexOf(s));
}
```

This piece of code provides the following output:

```
0  
1  
1  
3
```

How come? I've added on purpose two Strings containing the same characters ("Two"), but the object itself shouldn't be the same. What am I misunderstanding here? I was expecting this other output:

```
0
1
2
3
```

Comment: `indexOf()` always returns index of first occurence regardless of touching this index before.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[ArrayList.indexOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-) doesn't use reference equality to find the object. It uses the `equals()` method.  Notice what the documentation says (emphasis mine):

> returns the lowest index i such that (o==null ? get(i)==null : **o.equals(get(i)))**, or -1 if there is no such index.

Thus, it will match on the first string that is logically equal.

**EDIT:**

`Andremoniy`'s comment is absolutely right.  In the case of strings literals, because they are interned, they will also happen to have the same reference.  So your 2 strings `"Two"` are actually the same reference in this case.

```
System.out.println("Two" == "Two"); // will return true because they are the same reference.
```

Comment: In this case even if `ArrayList.indexOf()` would use reference equality, result will be the same.

Comment: Hm, I've  been using this `enhanced for` syntax for a while now, but now you clarified me this, it seems to me like a drawback, as I was using `indexOf()` to substitute the lack of an integer index inside the `enhanced for` (in comparision to the "traditional" `for` loop syntax). This also tells me that I have to think of another way for checking object equallity..

Comment: @JorgeGRC if you need an index, use a traditional for loop. There is nothing wrong with that. Using a for each loop if you then go back and look up the index for each element is inefficient at best.

Comment: @JorgeGRC Using indexOf() instead an extra counting variable becomes a major performance hog if your list is large, because indexOf() is complexity O(N), making your loop with indexOf() inside O(N*N).

Comment: @JorgeGRC, you can also have the enhanced for, and an additional variable for counting (just don't forget to `i++` at the end of the loop)

Answer (score 2):

It's simply because `indexOf` returns the *first* occurrence of the item in the list that is **equal** to the given string. See its [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-):

> Returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in this list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element. More formally, returns the lowest index `i` such that `(o==null ? get(i)==null : o.equals(get(i)))`, or -1 if there is no such index.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to note two points:

1. most probably you are using the same String-instance, since the constant `"Two"` gets interned, that is all occurences of this literal will refer to the same instance.
2. `List.indexOf()` doesn't compare items by `==` (that is object-identity) but using `equals()` - that is some class-defined way to compare two objects for equality (which makes perfect sense as otherwise you wouldn't be able to find something in the list unless you already have a reference to it). So even two different `String`-objects (e.g. created by `new String("Two")`) would still produce the same output.

For completeness the quote from the javadoc of `indexOf`(as already mentioned in the other answers:

> returns the lowest index i such that (o==null ? get(i)==null :
>   o.equals(get(i))), or -1 if there is no such index.

Comment: Just wondering: 1) why do you have doubts? Why *most probably*? It is the case where strings are the same indeed. 2) What new information comparing with @sstan's answer do you provide in your answer?

Comment: @Andremoniy 1) I don't recall if the spec requires literals to be interned or if it just offers the possibility - I've no doubts regarding oracles JVM. 2.) the "interned"-part of sstan's answer was added while I was still writing my answer, so it was just that he beat me by about 1 minute...

Comment: But in this case interning doesn't play any role, because of `equals` method used in implementation. In your answer this point appeals to be the reason of the problem

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't allow you to make a distinction between these two, but you have stumbled across the difference between (and disparity between) a *method* and a *function*.

Simply put a method may change the state of an object. A function will not. So calling your method `add(String)` will change the state of the `List`. Specifically, it adds the String to the list. `indexOf(String)` however is not a method, it is a function. Now sure, Java calls them methods because... that's what they call them. And it's conceivable that the implementation --could-- change the state. But we know that it doesn't, by contract.

A function, given the same inputs (of which the current state of the underlying object is part of those inputs) will always return the same result. Always. That's what's great about a function. You can call a function (a true function) as many times as you want and always get the same result as long as your inputs and the underlying data haven't changed.

Some folks at MIT did [research into the analysis](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.73.5717) of functions in Java (which to avoid confusion, they call "pure methods"). It would be nice if there was a framework that allowed you to specify that a particular method was indeed a function (or as they call it, was pure) and then have an analyzer make sure you didn't accidentally introduce a mutation into code protected by that annotation.